# How to share data in iphone from Telegraph to Whatsapp

Tags: iphone, whatsapp, telegram

In WhatsApp we can easily share the content with message app, mail, and even within WhatsApp.

But in Telegraph I cannot see this forward menu. I have tried to look in the settings for a permission option to allow Telegraph to share data with WhatsApp, but have been unsuccessful yet. Any guidance?

Comment: Is this a specific programming question or a question about an app itself? If it's a programming question it is not clear at all so please clarify and share some code of what you have tried. If it's just about the apps themselves then you are in the wrong place this site is for programming related questions

Comment: I think this question may be off-topic because it is about usage of an app and not about programming.

Comment: it is not a programming question. it is a question about an app itself. Kindly recommend a proper forum for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that it has to be done using a email or online repository as a two step process. And then re-post the data in Whats-app.